# Javascript & CSS Outlook Style Navigation Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for an outlook style navigation sidebar for my web application which looks similar to:

[image]

I know there are versions of this available as winform controls and through the Visual WebGUI system but these are Microsoft based solutions. What we are looking for is a strictly Javascript & CSS based solution or at the very least server independent. I am aware of similar solutions which have been made in the past which use jQuery's accordian plugin but that results in the sections moving up and down rather than being pinned to the bottom of the navigation bar the way the outlook solution works.

The basics of what we are after is...

- Title Bar
- Tree Navigation Section
- Section Navigation Buttons at Bottom
- Section Navigation Buttons Compressable To Single Row (Optional)

Would like to use an existing solution out there if there is one rather than needing to build my own.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there are lots and lots of different accordion and tree scripts found doing simple web searches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below links, these will help you to make build expected behavior.

[Example- Web Application User Interface as Outlook](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/how-to-create-web-application-user-interface-that-looks-like-outlook/)

[Outlook Style Menu With Collapse Side Menu](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14767/Outlook-Style-Menu-With-Collapse-Side-Menu)

Comment: Thanks that gives me a great start. Will use it with basic html, css, and javascript for now and when I get some time might have a play around with making a DHTML control based on it to make it easier for others to do it.